# UIBarButtonItem cutoff when UINavigationController presented in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios

My UIBarButtonItem is cut off in the nav bar when the navController is presented in a UIPopoverController. Any idea what's causing this?

screenshot of problem: http://www.flickr.com/photos/92771610@N02/8432176079

Here's the code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(saveAction:)];

vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;

UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease];

UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
popoverController.delegate = self;

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:buttonThatMakesThePopoverAppear.frame
                                   inView:self.view.superview
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                 animated:YES];
```

Thanks,
Gonzalo

Comment: You have sufficient "reputation" points here to include images in your posts, so you should probably do so in the future, rather than having external links. When adding/editing your question, the editor has an "insert picture" button in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you didn't respect the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Your custom `UIBarButtonItem` views and, custom background images for these elements should be 30 pixels high. The popover's bevel border is clipping your custom artwork correctly because, they shouldn't be that large.

When not presented via a `UIPopoverController`, these buttons appear fine in iOS 6, but only because there isn't a view clipping the bounds. Note in iOS 5 this does happen, so while you should appear to be good to go, make sure you test in the older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Elsewhere using the appearance manager to set custom images/background/title positions on UINavigationController and UIBarButtonItem was causing this because it didn't take into account the popover's bevel border. Solution: either reverse the values set for custom appearance before use or make the customizations work for all cases including use o nav bar in a popover.