# Left bar button item on NavigationBar not show full text when i present the viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

Left bar button with image not show full text, when i present that viewcontroller.[image]

i use below code for it

```
 let leftButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: buttonImg, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissVC))
        leftButton.title = title
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

And when i use `backbarbuttonitem` instead of `leftBarButtonItem` button not displayed.
please give need full suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItem cutoff when UINavigationController presented in UIPopoverController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630536/uibarbuttonitem-cutoff-when-uinavigationcontroller-presented-in-uipopovercontrol)

Comment: The reason backBarButtonItem is not displaying is because you are presenting the viewController instead of pushing it

Comment: check this post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546132/how-to-customize-the-navigation-back-symbol-and-navigation-back-text/43556837#43556837

Comment: @brl214 So, what should i do for presentViewController?